# Open Facebook/Twitter page by native app from other app

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

My app need to open a facebook page or twitter page such as: http://facebook.com/Apple or https://twitter.com/Apple by Twitter or Facebook app but i dont know how to do that.
I see we can use some command like fb://profile but i dont see command to open a page.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below to open in safari

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
```

or to open the native app

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"]]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"]];
}
```

Comment: it will be open page by web browers?

Comment: So you want to open the native FB app if its is installed on a users device?

Comment: Updated answer with ability to open fb app if it exists.